# Trigger for update comparing the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers, sql-update

the thing is that I need Update a row when 2 or more rows have the same data, so I need to compare the same column for update.. This will explain me better:

I have this trigger (but I don't want to delete anything)

```
DELETE n1
FROM Codes_Cost n1, Codes_Cost n2
WHERE n1.Code = n2.Code and n1.PeriodID = n2.PeriodID
AND n1.ID < n2.ID;
```

I need to do something similar but Updating another row. Something like this

```
UPDATE Codes_Cost n2
SET n2.Status = 'Old'
WHERE n1.Code = n2.Code and n1.ID < n2.ID
```

But obviously it doesn't work. 
What can I do? What kind of query can help?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood correctly, this should work.

```
UPDATE Codes_Cost 
SET Status = 'Old'
FROM Codes_Cost 
INNER JOIN Codes_Cost n2 ON Codes_Cost.Code = n2.Code 
WHERE
Codes_Cost.ID < n2.ID
```

Edited for ambiguous table name.

Comment: When doing an update with a self join you should alias both tables and update the alias. It makes the code very clear.

Comment: @SeanLange, yeah, the problem is that are 2 rows in the same table, not 2 tables

Comment: I understand. Look at the code here. Codes_Cost has a self join. I don't think you understood my comment.

Comment: Ok, i get it! This works :) 

**UPDATE c2
SET c2.Status = 'Old'
FROM Codes_Cost c1, Codes_Cost c2
WHERE c1.Code = c2.Code and c1.PeriodID = c2.PeriodID
AND c1.ID < c2.ID**

Comment: @EyMarie yes that is what I meant. I would make that a proper join instead of the old style but the result will be the same thing. :D

Comment: Yeah! I can't believe that I need to change only a word haha Really, thanks!